# i installed ubuntu 18.04.5 I change language to greek .On the top right of the screen there is a gr but keybord is english

Tags: keyboard, language-support

i just installed Ubuntu 18.04.5
I change language to Greek with super+space  .
On the top right of the screen there is a gr but keyboard is English

Comment: Maybe [bug #1890875](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1890875). Did you try to relogin?

Answer (score 0):

try this in the terminal;

L='gr' && sudo sed -i 's/XKBLAYOUT="\w*"/XKBLAYOUT="'$L'"/g' /etc/default/keyboard

read this link for other options https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/configure-keyboard-ubuntu/